# Identify container from file struct in Linux kernel

Tags: docker, linux-kernel

I'm writing a LSM and hooking the file_open function. At the moment I can print out the name of the file being accessed. However, when I access a file `/dir/file` in a docker container (the file does not exist outside the container), the printed path is `/dir/file`. Is this okay? Is the file in this path of the file system? Or is it stored in a different path? How can I tell which files are created inside a container and which are not?

I thought the vfsmountpoint might be different for these files, but it does not seem to be.